# ssh root into ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal

I have an Amazon ec2 instance running, and I have a non-root user set up that I use to ssh.

I have both the private key and certificate stored on my ~. This is the command that I'm using to try and log in, but it prompts me for a password (which I don't know/have).

```
$ sudo ssh -i mykey.pem root@ec2-amazoninstance.com
root@ec2-amazoninstance.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

How do I log into root not knowing this password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, once logged in as a user you use the command `su` to become root.

To directly login into the root account you need to make sure

- that you own the correct key or know the password
- root login is enabled in the SSH server

On a linux machine you would then run `ssh root@ip` to login as root on `ip`.

Comment: I don't have su privileges. I need to create a new ssh.

Comment: Updated my answer. If direct root login is disabled, it seems like Amazon doesnt want you to be root.

Comment: Thank you. Both are enabled, but it is prompting me for a password (which I do not know). How do I get around this?

Comment: Ask someone for the password who does know, or try to guess it.

Comment: A lot of EC2 information implies the user name is usually or always `ec2-user`.  Not true.  It can be `root` for CentOS, `ubuntu` for Ubuntu etc.  And for whatever reason, the user name is not documented with the AMI!  Very irritating.

Answer (score 0):

If the current user is a normal user then use "sudo su" command to become root user.